# How to add values from a random constructor class inside an array of your main class?

Tags: java, arrays

Here is the method I'm using on my main class "Arrays"

**My main class "Arrays" CANNOT contain any Libraries**

```
  public static int[] generateRandom(int n)
  {
    int[] randomArray = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < randomArray.length; i++)
    {
      //randomArray[i] =  ; // how do i fill it from the Random1 class?
    }
      return randomArray;
   }
```

I need to fill randomArray with random numbers from the class Random1. (I called it Random1 because for some reason it interfered with util.Random, but I would be happier with a class called Random.

```
 import java.util.Random;

 public class Random1
  {
   public Random1()
   {
    Random r = new Random(1);
    int num = r.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    System.out.print(" " + num);
  }
 }
```

Can you please help me with my 2 problems?

1) I need to fill the array in "Arrays" with the generated random numbers from Random1

2) I would like to be able to use it as Random and not Random1 because the integer bothers me.

Comment: probably instead of using Random1() constructor you need to use public static method with int return value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You need to refactor Random:

```
for (int i = 0; i < randomArray.length; i++)
{
  randomArray[i] = Random.generate();
}
```

Here is the new Random

```
 public class Random1
  {
   public static int generate()
   {
    java.util.Random r = new java.util.Random(1);
    int num = r.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    return num;
  }
 }
```

2) Do not import java.util.Random. Instead, always refer to it using its full name:

```
java.util.Random r = new java.util.Random(1);
```

Comment: Thanks you solved my 2nd problem. On the other hand I get an error saying :

Comment: Error: incompatible types
  required: int
  found:    Random

Comment: got it. Just changed my answer.

Comment: I got a last question if you can help me. My method takes in an integer which is used to set the array's size, but for some reason "int[] randomArray = new int[n];" creates N copies of my array.

Comment: I think "int[] randomArray = new int[n];" is fine. What you want is an array of length n, right? This is what you are getting. All cells will have zero. Then you need to add values to them.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public class Arrays{        
    public static void main(String [] args){
        generateRandom(5);
    }

    public static int[] generateRandom(int n)
      {
        int[] randomArray = new int[n];    
        for (int i = 0; i < randomArray.length; i++)
        {
          randomArray[i] = Random1.getRandomInt(); 
        }
          return randomArray;
       }
}

class Random1 {
    public static int getRandomInt(){
        Random r = new Random(1);
        int num = r.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        System.out.print(" " + num);
        return num;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how I can print that array ? when I try, it either prints the address or n times the array.

Comment: If you have Integer[] then you can use Array.DeeptoString, Since it is an int array, use a for loop and get each element and print it